# GEE error code while exporting Sentinel-2 cloud masked image

Tags: google-earth-engine, error, sentinel-2, cloud-cover

I have filtered a Sentinel-2 image and created a cloud mask for it based on its QA60 band. It works fine and displays with this mask applied. However, when I try to export it to a drive, I get the following error message:

> Error: Image.clipToBoundsAndScale, argument 'input': Invalid type.
> Expected type: Image. Actual type: ImageCollection.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it? My code is below.

```js
    //define the cloud mask layer
function maskS2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60');
  var cloudBitMask = 1 <<10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 <<11;
  
//layer called mask = the cloudy bits
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
  .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));
  
//'image' is a layer with the mask applied to it  
  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000);
}

//image collection is filtered
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2")
  .filterBounds(geometry)
  .filterDate('2015-08-26', '2015-08-28')
  .map(maskS2clouds);
  
//image with mask applied
Map.addLayer(dataset);

//exported to drive
Export.image.toDrive({
    image:dataset, 
    description: '2015_CLOUDFREE',
    folder: 'users/emilywest2',
    region: geometry.geometry,
    scale: 10,
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In GEE you can only export single ee.Images and not entire ImageCollections.

To get around this, you can use reducers on the ImageCollection. You can for example call `.first()` or `.toBands()` on your ImageCollection `dataset`. Like this:

```
Export.image.toDrive({
    image:dataset.toBands(), 
    description: '2015_CLOUDFREE',
    folder: 'users/emilywest2',
    region: geometry.geometry,
    scale: 10,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the data type of `dataset` is ee.ImageCollection, you can only export ee.Image.

To solve it, you can export `dataset` by for loop, and you need add `crs` parameter. Like this:

```
dataset=dataset.toList(dataset.size());
for(var i=0; i<dataset.size().getInfo(); i++){   
    Export.image.toDrive({
        image:ee.Image(dataset.get(i)), 
        description: '2015_CLOUDFREE_'+i,
        folder: 'users/emilywest2',
        region: geometry.geometry,
        scale: 10,
        crs:'EPSG:4326'
    });
}
```